# Entity Framework closes connection while debugging

Tags: entity-framework

We noticed that when we do F10 debugging and we spend time analyzing values of variables suddenly when we step on statement which queries something in the database through entity framework we get an error about connection being closed.

This only happens when debugging and not when running application. Also it only happens when we spend substantial time analyzing variables and not when quickly doing F10 presses.

This happens on multiple computers.

Answer (score 1):

This is because the default command timeout is 30 seconds.

You can set the command timeout for a context. In the constructor of your `DbContext` subclass add this code:

```
#if DEBUG
    this.Database.CommandTimeout = 300;
#endif
```

This will give you 300 seconds to keep an active command open.